# Mongoose/Express CastError for 1 of 2 exact same routes?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am attempting to *Model.find({})* **all** documents within a collection on two exactly similar express routes. On one of my routes, this happens no problem and all documents are returned. Yet, on a different express route with the **exact** same logic, I receive the following error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "featured" at path "_id" for model "Location"
```

Utilizing the **mongo shell** *db.locations.find()* I receive the documents **no problem**.

Here is my Schema for locations:

```
var mongoose              = require('mongoose');
var { pointSchema }       = require('../Geoschema-Types/GeoSchemas');

const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  PATH: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SOME_COLLECTION'}],
  PATH: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SOME_COLLECTION'}],
  PATH: String,
  location: {
    type: pointSchema,
    required: true
  },
  settings: {
    private: Boolean
  },
  meta: {
    created: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
    view_count: {type: Number, default: 0},
    tags: [String],
    likes: {type: Number, default: 0},
    numberOfComments: {type: Number, default: 0},
    numberOfShares: {type: Number, default: 0}
    },
    comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}],
    typeoflocation: String
});

LocationSchema.query.nearPoint = function(coordinates, maxDistance) {
 return this.where('location')
            .near({ center: { coordinates, type: 'Point' }, maxDistance, spherical: true })
};

LocationSchema.options.autoIndex = true;

LocationSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere" });

var Location = mongoose.model("Location", LocationSchema);

module.exports = Location;
```

In my root file *app.js* I have both of the routes placed in middleware each with different parent paths for their respective routers.

```
app.use('/test', require('./tests/routes/Test-Routes'))
app.use('/locations', require('./routes/Models/Locations/Location-Routes'));
```

**~ /Location-Routes** ------------ **FULL FILE**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { isLoggedIn } = require('../../../util/middleware/auth-util')
const { 
  addCommentUtil,
  LikePostUtil,
  deletePostUtil 
} = require('../../../util/middleware/post-actions-util');
const {
  newLocation, 
  findNear, 
  viewLocation
} = require('../../../controllers/Models/Locations/Location-Controllers')

// MODEL
const Location = require('../../../models/Location/LocationSchema')

router.route('/findnear')
  .post(findNear)

router.route('/:id')
  .get(isLoggedIn, viewLocation)

router.route('/featured')
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    Location.find({})
      .then(docs => {
        res.send(docs)
      })
      .catch(next)
  })

router.route('/newlocation')
  .post(isLoggedIn, newLocation)

router.route('/:id/addcomment')
  .post(isLoggedIn, addCommentUtil(Location));

router.route('/:id/like')
  .post(isLoggedIn,LikePostUtil(Location))

// DELETE ---------------------------------------------------------

router.route('/:id/delete')
  .delete(isLoggedIn, deletePostUtil(Location))

module.exports = router;
```

**~ /Test-Routes**

```
router.route('/featured')
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    Location.find({})
      .then(docs => {
        res.send(docs)
      })
      .catch(next)
  })
```

All other routes on the **~/Locations** router **work just fine**, including adding documents and deleting them... yet this one query returns the above error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "featured" at path "_id" for model "Location"
```

Using the **~/Test-Routes** route works just fine.

Comment: Can you show everything before `router.route('/featured')` in your `~ /Location-Routes`?

Comment: @Cuong Le Ngoc for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put `router.route('/:id')` before `router.route('/featured')` so when you call to `/featured`, it will recognize `featured` as `:id` and go to your `viewLocation` function in your `Location-Controllers`.

Changing your route to put `router.route('/featured')` before `router.route('/:id')` may solve the problem.