# How do i search a table in mongo db, to produce this desired url for my android app?

Tags: android, node.js, mongoose

```
router.get('/s/:restaurant', (req, res) => {
    Item.find({
        restaurant: req.query.restaurant
    }, {
        restaurant: 0
    }, (err, item) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.status(200).json({
                searchedByName: item
            })
            // res.send(req.params.restaurant);
        } else {
            console.log("Error in Retr`enter code here`ieving Items: " + 
 JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
        }
    })

})
```

The above code returns this

URL ==> https://sleepy-garden-51801.herokuapp.com/json/s/Galito

Producing the results as expected.

But when I try to call it in android using retrofit, I get this URL returned in the logs

https://sleepy-garden-51801.herokuapp.com/json/s?restaurant=Galito

How do I write a node function using mongoose, that can ensure that I return a similar function like this

https://sleepy-garden-51801.herokuapp.com/json/s?restaurant=Pizza%20Inn

Answer (score 1):

When you use `router.get('/s/:restaurant'...`, the expected url is *base_url/s/example_restaurant* and to get "example_restaurant" you need to call `req.params.restaurant`.

In your case, you used `req.query.restaurant`(that's the "?restaurant=Galito" in the url) so you don't need the `/:restaurant` part in your url, just need to check if `req.query.restaurant`exists before query.

Example based on your code:

```
router.get('/s', (req, res) => {
  if(req.query.restaurant) {
    Item.find({
      restaurant: req.query.restaurant
    }, {
      restaurant: 0
    }, (err, item) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.status(200).json({
            searchedByName: item
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Error in Retr`enter code here`ieving Items: " + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
      }
    })
  } else {
    // Do something
  }
})
```

Comment: https://sleepy-garden-51801.herokuapp.com/json/search?restaurant=Galito   no record with given id : search

Comment: Can you show your full route code? Look like there is a route match `/json/:id` or `/:id`.

Comment: // //get all restaurant by name
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {

    if (req.query.restaurant) {
        Item.find({
            restaurant: req.query.restaurant
        }, {
            restaurant: 0
        }, (err, item) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    searchedByName: item
                })
            } else {
                console.log("Error in Retr`enter code here`ieving Items: " + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2))
            }
        })
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
})

Comment: Is there any route match  `/:id` or `/:something`?

Comment: Look like your problem is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454920/mongoose-express-casterror-for-1-of-2-exact-same-routes/57455151#57455151 . Please check and let me know if it help.

Comment: but why is it that way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197917/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-mazakpe).