# Mongoose updateMany usage

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to update multiple values from a mongoDB document.

I'm using ExpressJS and Mongoose.

I believe to update multiple values, I should use updateMany().

However, it keeps giving me error message like this:

**'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "status" at path "_id" for model "order"'**

To give you details, here's my code below:

Order Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OrderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
    required: true
  },
  menus: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'menus',
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: 'pending'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('order', OrderSchema);
```

Also, here is my ExpressJS code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Order = require('../models/Order');
const User = require('../models/User');

// @route     PUT api/orders/status
// @desc      Update All Order status
// @access    Private
router.put('/status', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const { status } = req.body;

  const orderFields = {};

  if (status) orderFields.status = status;

  try {
    const orders = await Order.updateMany(
      { user: req.user.id },
      { $set: orderFields }
    );

    if (!orders || orders.length === 0)
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Order not found!' });

    res.json(orders);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

Do you guys have any idea what have I missed?

I've checked the mongoose API and googled out many sources, but I wasn't able to find my mistake here.

Comment: May be your problem related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57455151/11711316

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse `req.user.id` to ObjectID. You can achieve that by writing like this
 `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id);`

Comment: Hi Prashanth, thanks for your tip, but it didn't worked.